# Coldfusion Dynamic Directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, coldfusion

In Coldfusion we have three files that control our category.

```
subcat.cfm level1 subsubcat.cfm level2 results.cfm level3
```

We would like the following structure oursite.co.uk/level1/, oursite.co.uk/level1/level2/, oursite.co.uk/level1/level2/level3/

I have started setting up rules in mod_rewrite but of course when visiting the page oursite.co.uk/level1/ the images and css are the coldfusion files can't be found as everything is located based on the root directory.

Our first rewrite rule is this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /SubCat.cfm?catname=$1 [NC,L]
```

So is it possible to achieve this using apache mod_rewrite alone or will some manipulation in Coldfusion be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to exclude the pages you don't want:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|css|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
```

Place it on the line above the RewriteRule it applies to, and any request that matches the RewriteRule will then be checked against the previous RewriteCond to determine if the rewriting should occur.
<sub>(That might sound inside out, but it can be useful to know that the condition is checked after the rule's pattern.)</sub>

The `!` at the start of the pattern negates the condition, so if the Request URI (the section after the hostname and port) starts with `/images` OR `/css` OR `/favicon.ico` OR `/robots.txt` it will NOT be rewritten by that rule.

Comment: Hi @peter-broughton thank you for your help - AGAIN!! I have tried that rewritecond rule before the rewrite rule above but unfortunately the css and formatting is still not working. Do I need to change everything to an absolute path?

Comment: You shouldn't need absolute paths (the browser will do that automatically). Check in the net tab of firebug/devtools for what is being requested/received.

Comment: You shouldn't need an absolute path, but this is why I always use absolute paths from web root. It avoids issues like this.

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase: You don't need absolute paths, nor absolute urls. Whether you manually resolve it or you let the browser resolve it, the relevant factor (for mod_rewrite) is the value of the second item in the first line of the HTTP request - i.e. the text which is divided into request_uri and query_string - if the rewrite rule/cond patterns do not match, they wont perform the actions requested. Whether you specify the protocol, the host, and/or the full path is an independent choice to checking whether you have _correct_ paths. </pedantic> :P